# Regular expression for any occurrence of a date of the form `MMM. DD, YYYY`

Tags: regex

I'm refreshing my [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) skills in preparation for a job I'm starting.

I want to do a grep for any occurrence of a date of the form `MMM. DD, YYYY`.

Example: `Sep. 12, 2007`

The regular expression I came up with was:

```
grep "[[:alpha:]]\{3\}.[[:space:]][([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]\{2\})],[[:space:]][[:digit:]]\{4\}" file
```

My logic: three letters; a period; a space; one digit OR two digits; a comma; a space; four digits.

It may be more complex than it needs to be but really I just want to see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't escape the `.`s, and (more fatally) you didn't escape the parentheses so they were taken literally.  (With `grep` you need to use `\(...\)` for grouping.  `egrep` uses unescaped parentheses.)

Answer (score 2):

Perl regex might be a little easier to read and understand:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^\w\w\w\. \d\d, \d\d\d\d$/' somefile
```

Comment: just discovered "grep -P '^\w\w\w\. \d\d, \d\d\d\d$' somefile" works too, at least for my grep (Mac OS)

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to see where you went wrong? Here:

```
[([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]\{2\})]
```